# WCF service passing URI of a local file to a consuming application

Tags: c#, wcf, uri

I've got a WCF service that acts as a file store. Consuming applications running on the same LAN connect to the WCF service and download the files, usually as Stream objects.

However, I'm wondering if it's possible for the WCF service to somehow return a URI to the file instead of a Stream/bytestream. The WCF service itself does not run inside an IIS, but rather as a Managed Windows Service and is not exposed to the internet. It is only accessible over a LAN.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is SMB, AKA windows file sharing.

If what you want to do is share a file, then share a file...

Your scenario is useful when you require a different set of security and/or some interpretation of the data before it is sent.  SQL Server has the FILESTREAM type which literally returns an NTFS stream that you can write to.

I think your issue will come down to your security.  Provided you can setup a file share that has the same access levels as your app, there is no reason why you can't return a network path URI in your service.